# Copy a struct array to another struct array that is smaller

Tags: c, arrays, struct, copy

My struct array has 5 slots

```
struct router* router[5];
```

Lets say there are elements inside them, and then i make

```
router[3] = NULL;
```

Is it possible to rearrange the array so that the element in router[4] moves up to router[3], router[5] moves to router[4] etc.?

Comment: Of course it's possible. Just use assignment operator or `memmove`. `route[3] = router[4]; router[4] = NULL;`. Or please clarify your question if you are really trying to ask something different.

Comment: Since you probably need to make your code resilient to `NULL` entries anyway, you might consider doing just that, and leave `NULL` in the middle of your array.

Comment: Also note that there is no `router[5]` element as `router[4]` is the last valid element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
void delete(struct router** router, int which, int size) {
    int i;
    // If these pointers have no other references to them then
    // Then you should free the one being deleted at this point
    for(i = which; i < size - 1; i++) {
       router[i] = router[i + 1];
    }
    router[i] = NULL;

}
```